# Incorrect reshape of input data into keras lstm

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, keras, lstm

My x_train array (1526472 x 256):

```
[[0, 0, 1, ..., 0],
 [0, 1, 0, ..., 0],
 ...
 [0, 0, 0, ..., 1]]
```

My y_train array (8 x 2):

```
[[0, 1],
 [1, 0],
 ...
 [0, 1]]
```

What I want to do:

1) Reshape x_train array to 8 samples (190809 x 256 for each sample).
2) Reshape y_train array to consider as a label for each one of these 8 samples.
3) Put these into my lstm correctly.
4) Understand y_train error into my dense_2 layer.

What I am trying to do:

```
1) x_train = x_train.reshape(8, int(len(x_train)/8), 256)  
2) y_train = y_train.reshape(8, 2, 1)  
3) model.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(int(len(x_train)/8), 256), 
return_sequences = True, activation = 'sigmoid'))  
4) model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
```

lstm_1 error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 
shape (None, 1, 256) but got array with shape (8, 190809, 256)
```

dense_2 error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_2 to have 
shape (None, 190809, 2) but got array with shape (8, 2, 1)
```

Comment: What do the 8 samples represent? Not sure if I follow how you're going to train a model with just 8 samples. If this is some sort of time series prediction, and you're looking at a window of size 8, then your number of samples needs to be the first dimension of the input

Comment: Yes, I am trying to test with 8 samples first but is much more than this. I can split x_train array for more than 8 samples. You mean into input_shape of lstm? ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have shape (None, 8, 256) but got array with shape (8, 190809, 256)

Comment: Alright, if 8 is the amount of samples you have, you probably want `LSTM(256, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]) (...) )` which correspond to 190809 and 256 in this case?

Comment: Maybe I found the first problem: it does not accept int(len(x_train)/8 inside the lstm arguments. So, I put input_shape=(190809,256). But my dense_2 layer is giving me "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (None, 190809, 2) but got array with shape (8, 2, 1)
".

Comment: model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))

Comment: You've posted an error which comes from a line of code that you haven't posted. You need to post a full [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)